# Getting error : "'flow-ref' is pointing to 'main-flow-LoggingConnector-default-config-global-element-suffix' which does not exist" when running Munits

Tags: pom.xml, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, munit

Using a client logging connector from exchange in the main flow and it works fine. However, when I try to run Munits getting below error and no tests get executed:

[org/mule/extensions/smart/connector/module-logging.xml:309]: **'flow-ref' is pointing to 'main-flow-LoggingConnector-default-config-global-element-suffix' which does not exist**
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: [org/mule/extensions/smart/connector/module-logging.xml:309]: 'flow-ref' is pointing to 'main-flow-LoggingConnector-default-config-global-element-suffix' which does not exist

When I remove the logging connector from main flow it works without error and tests get executed.
The module-logging.xml file of the logging connector in the mule-plugin.jar is a read-only file.
Mocking the logging connector also doesn't work.

Below is the ln 309 in module-logging.xml :
<mule:flow-ref doc:name="Trigger Main Flow" doc:id="38f7e53c-4a0b-42d0-a9b3-2a70c216e7df" name="main-flow"/>

Tried to ignore this flow in pom.xml but no success.

Any way to ignore the logging connector when Munit runs or any work around would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How the connector was created? XML SDK, Java SDK or autogenerated? Is that main-flow part of the connector? Please add complete error log and the line that calls the connector from your flow.

Comment: hi @aled it worked without any change; not sure what was the issue;